# GitHub action cache restored, but cache-hit output false

Tags: github, npm, github-actions, npm-install

We are using caching to cache our node_modules, and then only run npm CI if that cache is not found.

This works as expected on all branches except one, despite the fact that the cache is clearly restored, the cache-hit output from the step is false.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: According to the note under `cache-hit` output i.e. "**`cache-hit` will only be set to `true` when a cache hit occurs for the exact `key` match. For a partial key match via `restore-keys` or a cache miss, it will be set to `false`.**". In your case, it seems to be an exact match but the `cache-hit` output is still `false`. You might want to [create an issue](https://github.com/actions/cache/issues/new/choose) on its repo to report this.